# how to send only one element to an other page by Post in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, post, hyperlink, response.redirect

I dunno whether I described my question well but I'm trying to send some element to other page either with a hyperlink or a Response.Redirect() and it's a key which make some access to the DB so I don't want to send it via url and get it. what should I do? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in session, or you could use some type of encoding and pass it in the QueryString.

Another option would be to store the value in ViewState and use `Server.Transfer` to direct the user to the other page. With `Server.Transfer` you'll still be able to access the ViewState from the other page like this:

```
private string ValueFromOtherPage
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["value"] != null)
        {
            return ViewState["value"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            string value;
            if (Context.Handler != null)
            {
                value = (Context.Handler as PreviousPageName).MyStoredValue;
                ViewState["value"] = value;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at this article for encoding/encrypting the QueryString:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/QueryStringEncryptionNET.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use session variables to store objects:
`Session["VariableName"] = yourObject;`

Note that overusing these session variables may lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can save it in a session
2. You can send a `GUID` which represent some info (in the QS)
3. You can use cookies.

Comment: `> You can send a GUID which represent some info (in the QS)` Where should that info stored? Also Using cookies is just like using URL to send the key.

Comment: it should be stored in the server side. ( and to be injected at first to the client - for him to send it later.)... for the cookies - its less visible. he didnt want it to be visible.( as much as QS)